# Update the last_login_at field only if last_login_at=null from the listener handle() method.

Tags: php, laravel

In my LogSuccessfulLogin Listener I am updating the last_login_at on user's successful login.but now I want like last_login_at should update only if the last_login_at is null or empty.can i do that with following code or not?

```
if($event->user->where('last_login_at','NULL'))
{
    $event->user->last_login_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $event->user->save();
}
```

LogSuccessfulLogin Listner

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class LogSuccessfulLogin
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $event->user->last_login_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $event->user->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) could help you:

```
if (empty($event->user->last_login_at)) {
    $event->user->last_login_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $event->user->save();
}
```